# Angular 12 : http services Id as dynamic

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm fresher for angular. I have one Api with id. can anyone explain how to take that id as dynamic. need that delete Api as dynamic

DeleteDetails: string = this.baseUrl + "company/delete?companyId=23480762-64d9-419a-8ef8-9fd544008997";

Comment: Do you have the companyId stored in the UI somewhere?

Comment: Stored in get method. I fetched all the companies and displayed those in a table. need to delete a particular row by clicking on the delete icon.  but this api has a particular id. I'm confusing how to take that dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string interpolation and build the url dynamically. As you mentioned that you have companyId in the get method you can do something like this:

```
DeleteDetails: string = `${this.baseUrl}company/delete?companyId=${this.getCompanyId()}`;
```

If its in a variable, you can do something like:

```
DeleteDetails: string = `${this.baseUrl}company/delete?companyId=${this.companyId}`;
```

Comment: Okay, if in case we didn't store companyId in get method. what is the possibility?

Comment: @Sahana you can store it in a variable and use it too. But it needs to be somewhere in the ui. UPdated the answer as well..

Comment: No Problem @Sahana, Please accept the answer if it helped you.